# Rails 4 path helpers and Kaminari pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, helper, kaminari

I am working on my first RoR website. You can consider it as a shop with products.

I use Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0, and Kaminari for pagination. 
Here is my route.rb file

```
  scope '(:locale)' do
    get 'product/all', as: :product
    get 'product/all', as: :home
    get 'all', :to => 'product#all'

    get 'page/:page', :action => :all, :controller => :product

    root 'product#all'
  end
```

As you see, I want to have pagination links like this one:

```
http://website/uk/page/2
```

And Kaminari creates links like that when I use *paginate* helper in views

However when I try to use path helper, I receive correct but not pretty links:

```
http://website/en/product/all?page=2
```

Here is the helper call:

```
product_path(page: 2, locale: I18n.locale)
```

As you see, locale scope works ok, but page is still appended as parameter.

So, here is the question:

**Is it possible to modify route.rb to have path helpers work the same way as kaminari helper?**

Comment: Move it higher up in the `routes.rb` file.  The first mapping that matches the route will be used.

Comment: @PinnyM, it does not help. I tried to put 'get 'page/:page', :action => :all, :controller => :product' after 'scope '(:locale)' do', but result is the same